# How to use IP for location in Power BI?

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

Currently trying to add a map of users, by IP, from an SQL-Server data source. The IP's either map to a wrong location, or don't map at all using Power BI's inbuilt lookup for them.

Is there a way to query location via the IP column? Or any known API to do this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this: [freegeoip.net](https://freegeoip.net)

```
http://freegeoip.net/xml/8.8.8.8
```

It returns:

```
<Response>
<IP>8.8.8.8</IP>
<CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
<CountryName>United States</CountryName>
<RegionCode>CA</RegionCode>
<RegionName>California</RegionName>
<City>Mountain View</City>
<ZipCode>94035</ZipCode>
<TimeZone>America/Los_Angeles</TimeZone>
<Latitude>37.386</Latitude>
<Longitude>-122.0838</Longitude>
<MetroCode>807</MetroCode>
</Response>
```

Or using JSON:

```
http://freegeoip.net/json/8.8.8.8

{"ip":"8.8.8.8","country_code":"US","country_name":"United States","region_code":"CA","region_name":"California","city":"Mountain View","zip_code":"94035","time_zone":"America/Los_Angeles","latitude":37.386,"longitude":-122.0838,"metro_code":807}
```

Comment: How would I go about incorporating this IN to power bi?

Comment: Open a data source, Use Connect to data -> Web and use this url. You'll get a table with this values. I've checked it, and returns a table with one column by field. https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-common-query-tasks/

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem, and here's what I did.

1. I created a **New table** with **distinct IP addresses** from the source data table.
2. Created a custom function which Queries the IP address and get the details for it (see at the bottom).
3. Clicked **Add Column** in the **Ribbon** and clicked on **Invoke Custom Function**
4. Once the query was completed, Clicked on the **New Column** and Expanded the table by **clicking Icon on Top Right of the column**.

--
The **Function Code** that worked for me is

```
= let
    Source = (#"IP Address" as text) => let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("http://freegeoip.net/json/" & #"IP Address")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Converted to Table"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table")
in
    #"Promoted Headers"
in
    Source
```

[Source](https://gqbi.wordpress.com/2017/03/14/power-bi-query-editor-getting-ip-address-details-from-ip-address/)